# Jenkins - extended choice parameter plugin script approval

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use a groovy script within the extended choice parameter plugin to return a list of options. The groovy script looks something like this: **return *"C:\AdminTool.exe GetOptions"*.execute().text**. Everytime I create a new job with a modified version of the command, I have to go and approve the script in ManageJenkins -> "In-process script approval". Is there an automated way to approve all the scripts? I might have 1000+ jenkins jobs that needs to be created with a slight change in the windows command.

Comment: @VimilSaju: Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Any workarounds? [Vimil Saju](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1219919/vimil-saju)